# Definition of Realm Database and handling Realm Objects in Swift 6 for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

For the past month I've been working on an App that uses Firebase for retrieving data from web-service and sending token notifications by Firebase.Messaging. Aside from that I am storing the data I get from Firebase to a local Database on each device. For that I use Realm, from MongoDB. When I start to define Realm and start a Realm instance, I've been shown multiple ways of doing so and I don't get the right one. I am gonna show you what I've been doing to start the Realm database and handle the objects I want to insert, update, delete and get from Realm.

```
import RealmSwift
import struct RealmSwift.SortDescriptor

protocol RealmDB: AnyObject {

  var database: Realm? { get }
  var config: DBConfig { get }

  func get<T: Object>(type: T.type) throws -> Results<T>
  func get<T: Object>(type: T.type, query: ((Query<T>) -> Query<Bool>)) throws -> Results<T>
  func save<S: Sequence>(objects: S) throws where S.Iterator.Element: Object
}
```

And this protocol is implemented in a class named RealmManager:

```
import RealmSwift

class RealmManager: RealmDB {
  internal var config: DBConfig
  private var _database: Realm?

  init (configuration: DBConfig){
    self.config = configuration
  }

  internal var database: Realm? {
    get{
      if _database == nil {
        do {
          try self.configure()
        } catch{}
      }
      return _database
    }
  }
```

Later I configure the database so its not readonly, gets the right url and declare writeType disk.

With all that done I need to handle some objects, lets do 2 for example.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Carga: Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: Int32
  @Persisted var idPedido: Int32
  @Persisted var kilograms: Double

  convenience init(_id: Int32, idPedido: Int32, kilograms: Double){
    self.init()
    self._id = _id
    self.idPedido = idPedido
    self.kilograms = kilograms
  }
}

class Pedido: Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: Int32
  var cargas = List<Carga>()

  convenience init(_id: Int32, listCargas: List<Carga>){
    self.init()
    self._id = _id
    self.cargas = listCargas
  }
}
```

How can I handle this objects, because when I try to get the first Carga from the list in Pedido I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
A little explanation on the structure I need to follow on handling this objects on my ViewController class or AppDelegate class would be helpful. I found multiple examples on how to use Realm in Swift but don't get my App to work properly.

Comment: The question is better asked in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77079502/realm-swift-exc-bad-access-when-trying-to-read-object?noredirect=1#comment135890044_77079502)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues in the code and sometimes simpler is better. Let me address a few things and maybe it will provide some clarity.

Let's correct the main issue: this code is not a managed Realm property

```
var cargas = List<Carga>()
```

...it's an in memory property but if you want that saved to disk, it needs to be managed. From the docs [Supported Types](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/supported-types/)

```
@Persisted var cargas = RealmSwift.List<Carga>()
```

It's a good idea to precede List with RealmSwift. to avoid a collision with Swift's List.

I assume the (primary) keys are pulled from Firebase? If so, this `id: Int32` is the "wrong" datatype. You'll need to use a String as [Firestore @DocumentId's](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/swift-codable-data-mapping#mapping_to_and_from_simple_types_in_documents_using_codable) are best handled by strings. However, if the Realm objects handle their own primary keys, this is the preferred method

```
class Carga: Object{
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
```

Then let's create a Carga and add it to a List in Pedido

```
let c = Carga()
let p = Pedido()
p.cargas.append(c)
let realm = gGetRealm() //see below
try! realm.write {
   realm.add(p) //this adds a Pedido AND adds the Cargo too!
}
```

then to read

```
let realm = gGetRealm() //see below
let results = realm.objects(Pedido.class)
for p in results {
   print(p.cargas)
}
```

We like to keep thing simple so getting our Realm instance is just a matter of a global function gGetRealm (I omitted error checking for brevity)

```
func gGetRealm() -> Realm {
   let pathToThisRealmFiled = //specify the path
   var config = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
   config.fileURL = pathToThisRealmFile
   let realm = try Realm.init(configuration: config)
   return realm
}
```

While generics and protocols have their place, we find they sometimes overcomplicate dealing with Realm objects. e.g. Realm objects already conform to RLMObject and there are no sublasses of Realm so the protocol may be extraneous. It depends on the use case though.

Comment: @DMarMon That link appears to be broken. Since you have brand new code, Please add an edit to your question with your updated code, troubleshooting and errors you're experiencing and we'll take a look. It may actually require a separate question but lets see if that's needed first.